# Cant start cinnamon-settings vluetooth module

Tags: bluetooth, python3, settings, cinnamon, glib

I get this error when clicking on bluetooth in cinnamon-settins:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/blueberry/blueberry.py", line 5, in <module>
    import rfkillMagic
  File "/usr/lib/blueberry/rfkillMagic.py", line 5, in <module>
    from gi.repository import GLib
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gi'
```

What can i do???